# Looking for a PowerShell script to compare two folders recursively

Tags: powershell

Just thought it would be nice to have one but my PS skills are not up to task. Anybody can share theirs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easy enough to do something simple:

```
$d1 = get-childitem -path $dir1 -recurse
$d2 = get-childitem -path $dir2 -recurse
compare-object $d1 $d2
```

More sophistication required depending on the definition of difference.

Comment: This works... Is it possible to include relative path into comparision results, as well as some output while this is processing?

Comment: Figued it out - add -name to each of get-childitem, you'll get necessary results faster and you'll see the progress

Comment: '-name' is a new one for me :-), I'll have to remember that.

Comment: Is there any easy way to get this method to compare the contents of the files?

Comment: @Fopedush `Compare-Object` compares collections of objects. If they are two sets of strings that are the contents of two files, then the files' contents are compared.